# iOS 11 issue of Navigation Title and navigation Buttons not appearing while presenting viewcontroller using navigationrootviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, swift3, ios11, xcode9

Prior to iOS 11, the UINavigationBar buttons and title are being displayed correctly.

After downloaded Xcode 9 with iOS 11 and, after building and running without doing changes, both navigation buttons and the title are not being displayed anymore.

For presenting ViewController I am using below code, its might be an issue of adding viewcontroller in navigation rootviewcontroller:

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyVC") as? MyVC {
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any alternate of the above code to present viewcontroller and also support navigationcontroller which are presenting.

Any help is appriciated..!!

Comment: can you post some code of navigation buttons code ?

Comment: @kirtimali If we use navigation controller then it itself manage navigation buttons. No need to do any code to display bar buttons.

Comment: no,  have to do code to display uibarbutton item to letfbar or rightbar

Comment: My project related to manage folder structure like Dropbox. And i used default navigation controller not custom.

Comment: can you explain me more which button does not showing  and attach screen shot  previous version and current version ?